# How to remove/change saved SVN passwords?

Tags: security, password, svn, gnome-keyring

I'm using SVN from Eclipse and it has a feature that allows you to save the SVN user and password. It think it uses something called gnome-keyring to do so. The problem is that now I need to use another user to access the SVN repository, but I'm unable to change the previous set user. How can I change/remove that previous user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Goto **Applications>>Accessories>>Passwords and Encryption Keys**.
- Open the Passwords Menu Entry.
- In the list you will see the password for eclipse svn.
- Delete it and then start eclipse and enter new credentials.